# Raspberry Pi Wlan Connection Crash/ Multiple networks in parallel

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, wlan, lan

I have a raspberry pi 3 model b which uses LAN to connect to my router (fritz box, internet, ...) and in parallel a wlan connection to a different wlan router (a tello drone providing a wlan network).

When I start my net core software which listens and send udp packets to this drone network, this works on my rapsberry pi 4. On the rapsberry pi 3, the wlan gets lost after a few seconds (this means i cannot see the devices after the crash any more).

This is the setup (ifconfig, eth0 -> fritz box router, wlan0 -> drone):

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.178.48  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
    inet6 2003:d2:ff3a:ca00:d365:75c1:64f7:4d95  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::4d57:91fb:dfc7:6b34  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:27:eb:54:8c:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6000  bytes 890224 (869.3 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7441  bytes 4995016 (4.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
    RX packets 32  bytes 4209 (4.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 32  bytes 4209 (4.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.10.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
    inet6 fe80::5dc2:6615:7dc0:5375  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:27:eb:01:d9:ad  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 10  bytes 1600 (1.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 244  bytes 46987 (45.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I receive a error message is /var/log/messages (note: power management ist disabled by me):

```
Mar 28 18:09:59 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  387.901642] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save disabled
Mar 28 18:13:34 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  602.034411] mmc1: card 0001 removed
Mar 28 18:13:34 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  602.100223] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc1 (72 bytes)
Mar 28 18:13:34 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  602.144081] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x5e (135 bytes)
Mar 28 18:13:34 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  602.145675] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x63 (3 bytes)
Mar 28 18:13:34 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  602.156786] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x11 (33 bytes)
Mar 28 18:13:34 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  602.194812] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xf0 (73 bytes)
Mar 28 18:13:34 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  602.211922] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc8 (52 bytes)
Mar 28 18:14:14 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  642.634521] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc1 (72 bytes)
Mar 28 18:14:14 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  642.691858] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x5e (135 bytes)
Mar 28 18:14:14 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  642.693984] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x63 (3 bytes)
Mar 28 18:14:14 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  642.708667] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x11 (33 bytes)
Mar 28 18:14:14 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  642.757611] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xf0 (73 bytes)
Mar 28 18:14:14 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  642.780052] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc8 (52 bytes)
Mar 28 18:15:07 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  694.944685] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc1 (72 bytes)
Mar 28 18:15:07 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  695.024881] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x5e (135 bytes)
Mar 28 18:15:07 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  695.027818] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x63 (3 bytes)
Mar 28 18:15:07 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  695.048708] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x11 (33 bytes)
Mar 28 18:15:07 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  695.119219] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xf0 (73 bytes)
Mar 28 18:15:07 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  695.151731] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc8 (52 bytes)
Mar 28 18:16:23 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  771.114777] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc1 (72 bytes)
Mar 28 18:16:23 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  771.273867] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x5e (135 bytes)
Mar 28 18:16:23 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  771.279684] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x63 (3 bytes)
Mar 28 18:16:23 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  771.320348] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x11 (33 bytes)
Mar 28 18:16:23 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  771.456273] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xf0 (73 bytes)
Mar 28 18:16:23 raspberrypi2 kernel: [  771.518587] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc8 (52 bytes)
```

Uname -a:

```
Linux raspberrypi2 5.10.103-v7+ #1530 SMP Tue Mar 8 13:02:44 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

"Ifconfig" after crash does not contain any device named "wlan0" any longer and I do not see the wlan connection symbol in raspberry menu on the upper.

In another forum I read, that the problem might be that theese network devices have the same subnet mask (so the connection with lower priority is cancelled).

So the question is:

1. Do I have to change the subnet masks and when yes to what (I compared the "route" output both from Raspberry 3 and 4 - they are equal)?
2. Any ideas why same code works on raspberry 4 and not on 3 (same operation system, kernel version, etc.)? Diffence is the hardware. Note: "rpi-update" did not solve the problem.
3. Any other ideas how to fix?

Thanks, best regards